# Why is onAttach (Activity activity) deprecated?

Tags: android, android-activity

After updating the SDK to API level 23, I found that `onAttach (Activity activity)` is deprecated and the new method is `onAttach (Context context)`. can any one enlighten me on why this change was made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it has basically been to expand the scope of the method, but the official [changelog](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html) doesn't say anything about it.

As you can see in the changelog they have removed the `void onAttach(Activity)` but they added a new one with the same name, and it says that is deprecated in the [Android Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)).

As [richq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4596/richq) commented, the [support version of Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onAttach%28android.content.Context%29) also deprecates onAttach(Activity) and has an onAttach(Context) that can be used instead on all Android versions right back to prehistoric ones.

To adapt to this new changes you can follow this steps:

- Change the argument type of onAttach callback from `Activity` to `Context`. For unknown reason, this modification results in the fact that the method `onAttach(Context)` is not called anymore during the fragment lifecycle.
- Move the code that was in `onAttach` method to `onCreate` one since it gets still executed.

With this modification, the app turns to run as before. No additional import statements are required.

Comment: The [support version of Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onAttach%28android.content.Context%29) also deprecates onAttach(Activity) and has an onAttach(Context) that can be used instead on all Android versions right back to prehistoric ones.

Comment: I'll edit the answer with your comment because I've found it very useful.

Comment: "Change the argument type of `onAttach` callback from `Activity` to `Context`. For unknown reason, this modification results in the fact that the method `onAttach(Context)` is not called anymore during the fragment lifecycle." This confuses me - did you mean to say "`onAttach(Activity)` is not called anymore during the fragment lifecycle"?

Comment: No, if you see the doc, you can see that not only the argument has changed, also the behaviour of the method has changed.

Comment: Pretty sure google has a deal with coffee producers; make subtle (and unnecessary) changes to keep developers going all day long on coffee.

Comment: @arodriguezdonaire this doesn't answer the question "Why?". There are other more relevant questions on "How to fix the code?" related to this change. "I think it has basically been to expand the scope of the method" suggest that you can now attach to more than just activities, but how and where?

Answer (score 4):

Until this change happened, a fragment could only be attached to an activity. After this change Google can work towards attaching fragments to Services too. Something like how Facebook chat heads work, they could have fragment floating outside an activity too.